# PHP manager check phpInfo shows wrong version

Tags: php, iis, php-manager

I have `PHP Manager` on the server. And there are three versions of `php` installed `7.0, 5.3, 7.2`. Now `7.0` is in use. When I change PHP version and check `phpinfo()` from the `PHP Mangaer` I still see `7.0` version, but `php.ini` file changes as in the picture bellow. Why php version doesn't change?
[image]

when I click `check phpInfo()` I see 
[image]

Comment: The first screenshot shows that you set PHP 7.2 at server level, while the second screenshot only shows a page based on your selection of a site. Due to the fact that IIS allows you to configure different PHP versions for sites, that page can of course show 7.0 if that's what you configured for that site. You probably got it working by fixing the version.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you have 2 different PHP on your server.
On the screenshots php.ini exists in 2 different places.

screen 1 https://prnt.sc/jxylmu
screen 2 https://prnt.sc/jxylu6

Try to find all php.exe php-cgi.exe files.

Comment: For each version I've used the correct php-cgi.exe, but now  the problem is solved and if be honest I don't know after what the problem solved. Thank you.